# Cant swipe and remove notification on foreground service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I have 3 activities: activity3.java, notificationService.java and firebaseNotification.java.
In activity3.java I made a notification channel.
code:

```
public void openChannel(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "deliveryinfo",
                "Delivery Information",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager manager =getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

notificationService.java is a Service, code is:

```
public class notificationService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity3.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "deliveryinfo")
                .setContentTitle("Condition Changed")
                .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("extra"))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.deliver)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
                .build();
        startForeground(1,notification);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in firebaseNotification.java I am getting data from firebase and passing it to notificationService.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), notificationService.class);
                        intent.putExtra("extra", snapshot.child("condition").getValue().toString());
                        startService(intent);
```

But I have a problem. I cant clear that notification when it comes. I looked for the solution everywhere, but there is no info about that.

P.S. firebaseNotification.java extends Application and its declared in manifest(android:name=".firebaseNotification"). **I tried to write `stopSelf()` in notificationService, under the `startForeground(1,notification)` and `notificationmanger.cancel()` but it doesnt help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Foreground services must display a Notification.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

The only way to get rid of the notification is to make your service not run in the foreground.

Comment: Ok, but how to show notification when data in firebase changes without foreground service when app is closed?(and withour firebase cloud messaging)

Comment: The best option is to use Firebase Cloud Messasing. The other option is that you run a service as a foreground service and listen for the changes yourself, but then you have to display a notification. That's Google's way of telling the user *This app runs in the background now and drains your battery*.

Comment: You can create a 2nd Channel and a 2nd NOTIFICATION_ID for Push Notifications and leave 1st Channel (the current you have) only for Foreground Notification (I suggest to set it to LOW Priority if you will use it only for foreground notification)